# How to fix this if choice error in my Python text based game?

Tags: python

I need help with this code;

```
input()
print("Created by Mr.StiK")
input()
print('In a dark and creepy cave... You got your consciousness back...')
input()

print("Then you remember... you've no time to waste...")
input()


    
unit = input("Type the command 'wake' to start your adventure... ").lower()
    
while unit.lower() == "wake":

    if unit.lower() == "wake":
        print("And you starts your adventure...")
        break

    if not unit.lower() == "wake":
        print("Sorry, unidentified command. Please type 'wake'")
```

The error;

When you type the command wrong, it does not say anything, just skips the code.

And when we input nothing, we get nothing.

And then when we say anything, the program crashes, with this;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'wake' is not defined
```

Please I need help with this.

PS: IF YOU CAN ALSO NEED TO RE-WRITE THE CODE WITH A BETTER CODE/ENGINE, PLEASE, IT WILL BE ACCEPTED TOO.

Comment: the while loop's test is the problem.

Comment: In your own words, what do you think `while unit.lower() == "wake":` means? If `unit.lower()` is not equal to `"wake"` before the loop is reached for the first time, do you expect the loop to run at all? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your WHILE_LOOP and INPUT to this

```
while True:
    unit = input("Type the command 'wake' to start your adventure... ").lower()
    if unit == "wake":
        print("And you starts your adventure...")
        break
    else:
        print("Sorry, unidentified command. Please type 'wake'")
```